# Accidentally uninstall rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2

Trying to reinstall RSpec, and I can't seem to re-add its command to my bin folder.

```
Mac-Users-MacBook-Pro:bin macuser$ rspec
-bash: /usr/bin/rspec: No such file or directory

>> which rspec
#> returns nothing.
```

I tried `sudo gem install rspec --prerelease` a dozen times, `bundle install` , and nothing seems to give.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and uninstalled all of rspec2.

Then instead of `sudo gem install rspec --prerelease`, I did `sudo gem install rspec-rails --prerelease` which worked.

Then I followed the explicit directions to delete certain files that were floating around in previous beta releases. Everything is copacetic.

Answer (score 2):

Hey Trip, I'm pretty sure the command is `spec` and not `rspec`.

**Edit**

Ok, so, I took another look, you are right the rspec command is included in rspec2...

So, here is a Gemfile I have which properly installs rspec w/ bundle install

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
gem 'mysql'

group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.0.0.beta.17"
end
```

In my case, I'm using rvm & it is installed to:

`/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-head@<my gemset>/bin/rspec`

Comment: Yah I did all of that. I didn't install RVM on this box yet ( because I don't have to yet :)   ). I think what may have happened is that when I uninstalled it, it only uninstalled half of it, and when I reinstalled it, it thinks that the whole thing is there even though it is missing.